# Inequality involving e

Tags: limits, inequality

I wish to prove the following inequality, for $x>1$:$$\frac{(1+(1/x))^{
(x/2)+(1/3)}}{(1-(1/x))^{(x/2)-(1/3)}}> e$$ I believe that the limit,as x tends to infinity of the LHS, is e,but cannot go further.Taking logarithms of each side does not seem to help. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

This is the same as proving that
$$\log \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}-\frac{x}{2}}
   \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}\right) \gt 1$$ Expand the logarithm
$$\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{x}{2}\right) \log \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{x}{2}\right) \log \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ Use Taylor series for large values of $x$ and you should notice that many terms disappear.

Moreover, if you take the time of combining the usual series of the logarithms, you should arrive to an infinite summation in which all coefficients are positive.

**Edit**

Since, in comments, you told me that, not only you solved the problem, even more, that you reversed the inequality changing the $\frac 13$ to $\frac 12$.

I can now report the result for the most general case:
$$f=\log \left(\left(a-\frac{b}{x}\right)^{d-c x} \left(a+\frac{b}{x}\right)^{
   d+cx}\right)$$ where $(a,b,c,d)$ are positive numbers.

Written as an infinite summation, we have:
$$f=2 \left(\frac{b c}{a}+d \log (a)\right)+\frac 1a \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac { 2(bc-ad)n-ad}{(2n+1)n }y^{n}\quad \text{with} \quad y=\left(\frac{b}{a x}\right)^2$$ which, if $a=b=1$ reduces to
$$f=2c +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac { 2(c-d)n-d}{(2n+1)n }y^{n}\quad \text{with} \quad y=\frac{1}{x^2}$$ which confirms your observation.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have now proved the inequality .Incidentally, if you substitute 1/2 for 1/3 in the LHS of the inequality you can then show that the LHS<e.

Comment: @D.Spencer. Have a loo at my edit..

Comment: Thank you for the most instructive generalisation

Comment: @D.Spencer: if you include the things you've found in your question, it would not only be helpful to others on the site, but it would also keep your question from being closed (and possibly deleted). See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for details.